# Can we configure the newsfeed show up duration after servers reboot?

Tags: newsfeed

We have SharePoint 2013 farm. Our company users will visit their Mysite every working day (Monday to Friday). Last Saturday night we have rebooted our servers. On Monday, users found all the feed before Friday are disappeared on Mysite.

After some investigation, we found all the feed can be searched out with search center. So the feeds are stored to each Mysite or team site database properly. My question is that if SharePoint can still show up the feeds on Friday (1 day before reboot), can we configure it to keep showing more days (e.g. 7 days) of feeds after farm reboot?

Answer (score 1):

See about the Distributed Cache. Those items are stored in the cache, since March 2013 PU. No way to get them back for the News Feed.
You should stop this service gracerully before rebooting one server, such that it's copied to other servers in your farm. Reboot that server, wait for it to come up and do for other servers similar.

Use the Stop-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance cmdlet with the -Graceful .

Comment: After the server is rebooted, will the SPDistributedCacheService recovered back to start-up status?

Comment: Also I don't understand why the newsfeed on Friday still show up after reboot.

Comment: I now see it is possible to repopulate. See this TechNet article, a lot to read... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219560(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Due to our policy we need to reboot the servers at mid-night. Hence I cannot ensure the graceful stop service will be completed before shutdown. What would happen if we shutdown machine before data transfer complete?

Comment: Your cache might get in a corrupted state, but not 100% sure TBH.

Comment: I have tested on one of WFE, "Stop-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance -Graceful" and "Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance". Then reboot. The user consolidated newsfeed lost all newsfeed BEFORE today. Only today's newsfeed are shown. Also the timer job "UPS application - Feed Cache Repopulation Job" is running every 5 min

Comment: Why did you remove the cache instance??? That is probably the reason as you should not have done that.

Comment: I just found that if I click the user name, I can get the user's newsfeed older than today. However the mysite "Default.aspx" page just do not show any newsfeed older than today. The feed repopulation actually working but it doesn't list newsfeed old than 1 day on default page!

Comment: I run "Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance" according this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj219613.aspx#graceful